# Unable to load rJava in RStudio

Tags: java, r, macos, rstudio

I have been trying to load `rJava` onto my RStudio setup and it just won't work. It installs fine but doesn't load when I use the command `library(rJava)`.

Here's what I've tried:-

1. I have installed the latest version of jdk which is jdk 9.0.1.
2. I have tried changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the jdk location.
3. I have tried everything in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738974/rjava-load-error-in-rstudio-r-after-upgrading-to-osx-yosemite) as well but it didn't work.

I have attached the screenshot of the error message:

[image]

I am working on a MacBook.

Comment: I hope JRE is there i.e. `java -version` prints the version. Plus I remember in mac rJava installation is tricky due to gcc version as well.

Comment: @abhiieor Yes, I get the version when I run the command

Answer (score 1):

There is a very specific sequence of steps that must be taken to get `rJava` to work on a Macbook, as documented in [rJava Issues #86](https://github.com/s-u/rJava/issues/86#issuecomment-261039681).

1. Download and install Java from Oracle
2. Uninstall any previously installed version of rJava
3. Add JAVA_HOME to your .bashrc
4. Close & restart terminal, R and RStudio sessions so they pick up the updated JAVA_HOME
5. Use `install.packages()` to install rJava

See the URL link above for additional details on each step.

Comment: This did not solve the problem either. I am still getting the same error

Comment: Also, I get a new error when I run the command sudo R CMD javareconf -n. It shows that it could not find jni.h.